# Google Maps API v3 cannot make a marker...

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I’ve just built up a customized tiles map site : http://shuttle.wanglingjie.net/memoire/memoire.html.

But I have a trouble with making a marker on it. Once I added the new marker code:

```
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            map: map
            }
        );
```

The maker doesn’t show up and the js reports an error with the following message:

Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property : [object HTMLDivElement]

Any ideas? Thank you for your attention. :)

Answer (score 2):

`map` is null. In firebug, your site gives this error:

```
map is not defined
http://shuttle.wanglingjie.net/memoire/memoire.html
Line 129
```

Your javascript code is badly laid out, so it is hard to see what you have done wrong. I think the problem is that your `window.onload` function does not have a closing bracket: `}`.

You should lay your javascript out so that all code contained within brackets has the same amount of indent. For instance, the code you have posted should look like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        map: map
    }
);
```

It's also acceptable to write it like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map
});
```

This makes your code easier to read, and will help you find bugs.

If you need more help, please edit your question to include the full body of your function, correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code given in the link I noticed that the block that creates the marker is outside the function that creates the map. That's why the marker doesn't see the variable `map`.